# Two different vision of Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> First one: Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of real-valued continuous functions that separates points and vanishes at no points. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}(X)$.
>
> Second: Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of real-valued continuous functions that separates points. Then $\mathcal{A}=C(X, \mathbb{R})$ or $\mathcal{A}=\{f\in C(X, \mathbb{R}): f(x_0)=0 \}$. The first altenative holds iff $\mathcal{A}$ contains the constant functions.

Are these two theorems the same? I know that if $\mathcal{A}$ is closed then $\bar{\mathcal{A}}=\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{C}(X)$.

Comment: Your second statement does not make sense. You are assuming that function in $\mathcal A$ vanish at no points. How can you have the second alternative?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Sorry, no this one.

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: @WillM. So how to prove that?

Comment: Second implies First trivially; the reverse implication holds by considering $\mathscr{B}$ to be the algebra generated by $\mathscr{A}$ and the constant functions.

Comment: @WillM. Why we have  $\mathcal{A}=\{f\in C(X, \mathbb{R}): f(x_0)=0 \}$? The first one states that it vanishes at no points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the second theorem implies the first one.

To prove the first one implies the second, assume the first one holds and let $\mathscr{A}$ be an algebra that separates points and vanish at one point $x_0$ (if it did not vanish at any point, we can conclude $\overline{\mathscr{A}}$ is all the continuous functions by the first theorem). Clearly $\overline{\mathscr{A}} \subset \{f;f(x_0)=0\}.$ Consider $\mathscr{B}$ to be algebra generated by $\mathscr{A}$ and the constant functions, in other words, $\mathscr{B}$ consists of all functions $f + c,$ where $f \in \mathscr{A}$ and $c$ a constant function. Then $\overline{\mathscr{B}}$ is all the continuous functions. This means , in particular, that if $f(x_0)=0,$ then there exists a sequence of functions $g_n = f_n + c_n \in \mathscr{B}$ converging uniformly to $f.$ Upon evaluating at $x_0,$ we see that $c_n \to 0$ and then $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Q.E.D.

Comment: Why does exist $g_n$  converging uniformly to $f$?