# An algebra that separates points and vanished at no point is unital (Stone–Weierstrass theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $(K,d)$ be a compact metric space and $A\subseteq \mathcal{C}(K)$ be a subalgebra. Is it true that if $A$ separates points (i.e., for every $x_1\ne x_2$ in $K$ there exists $f\in A$ s.t. $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$) and vanishes at no point (i.e., for every $x\in K$ there exists $f\in A$ s.t. $f(x)\ne 0$), $A$ is unital? And are these conditions sufficient for $A$ to be dense in $\mathcal{C} (K) $?

This question rose while seeking the necessary conditions of the Stone–Weierstrass theorem. I've seen [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3474425/two-different-vision-of-stone-weierstrass-theorem) here, but no one really answers this. It seems that this is true, as I couldn't find a counterexample, but I wasn't quite able to construct a constant function in $A$ by these assumptions.

Comment: What about $K=[1,2]$ and $A = \mathrm{span}(x^k:k\geq 1)$?

Comment: @PhoemueX That seems to work, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can write this as an answer to your own question. Too lazy right now :P

Comment: As for the second question (density), the answer is yes and it follows immediately from the version of Stone-Weierstrass for locally compact spaces.